# Hide update and cancel button after click on update button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, magento

We are using this code for updating the price.

Once we click on "update" button it's displaying as like in image.

What we need is once we click on "update" button, then "Update" and "cancel" button should hide. Now once we refresh the page, then only "Update" and "cancel" button is hidden, but it should happen before refeshing the page. I need something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/g1v9x1bt/

For the "cancel" button, it's working fine. Once we click on the "cancel" button, then "Update" and "cancel" button is hiding

```
<span class="label pro_status">
    <?php //echo $products->getPrice(); ?>

        <span id="valueprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>"><?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?></span>
    <input type = "text" id = "price_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" onkeydown="validateNumbers(event)" "name = "price" value = "<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>" style = "display:none"/>


    <!-- aki 2 -->
    <span class="label wk_action" id="edit_link_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>">
<img onclick="showFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" 
src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('marketplace/images/icon-edit.png'); ?>"/>
        </span>  
    <p id="updatedprice_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red;">Updated</p><br/>
    <button id="price_update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateFieldPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
                <span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
                                                        </button>
    <button id="price_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetPrice('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" style="display:none" >
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
                                                        </button>                                                       
                                                    </span>
```

**script**

```
<script>
function updateFieldPrice(product_id)
        {
            var priceId = '#price_'+ product_id;
            var valueId = '#valueprice_'+ product_id;
            var updatedqty = '#updatedprice_'+ product_id;


            var editLink = "#price_edit_link_"+ product_id;
            var updateButton = "#price_update_button_"+ product_id;
            var resetButton = "#price_reset_button"+ product_id;
            var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldPrice/')?>';

            $wk_jq(priceId).toggle()

            $wk_jq(editLink).hide();
            $wk_jq(updateButton).show();
            $wk_jq(resetButton).show();

            $price = $wk_jq(priceId).val();
            jQuery(valueId).html($price);
            hideReset(product_id);
```

Comment: Per my understanding, you just want to hide buttons on click of update. right?

Comment: yes, you are right....

Comment: i want some thing like this : https://jsfiddle.net/g1v9x1bt/

Comment: You can use `$(elementSelector).hide()`

Comment: can you give complete code.....

Comment: is this what you are trying to achieve? [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g1v9x1bt/1/)

Comment: what codei  need to chnage and what code i have to add.....

Comment: i need to change this : var resetButton = "#price_reset_button"+ product_id; change this to var resetButton = "#price_reset_button_"+ product_id  please post ur comment as answer.....

Comment: I have added an answer explaining changes that I have made and what else can be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So per your requirement, following [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/g1v9x1bt/1/) will help you.

#### Element Object

```
var $updateButton = $wk_jq("#update_button_"+ product_id);
```

You can disable button using following code:

```
var $updateButton = $wk_jq("#update_button_"+ product_id);
```

Reset button object

```
var $resetButton = $wk_jq("#update_button_"+ product_id);
```

#### Disable

Here you are updating disabled property of only update button.

```
$updateButton.prop('disabled', true);
```

#### Hide

```
$updateButton.hide();
$resetButton.hide();
```

Comment: please help me here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33650823/convert-vertical-menu-to-horizontal-menu-using-css?noredirect=1#comment55075519_33650823